# Windows Phone 8 and Neural Network

Tags: windows-phone-8, neural-network, aforge

I am wondering to using Neural Network frameworks on Windows Phone 8. I am searching on google but I can not found illustrative information. Is it possible ? Can using like a Aforge or another frameworks.
Thanks in advance. (sorry my language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [AForge.NET Framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) and its "extension" [Accord.NET Framework](http://accord-framework.net/) have been adapted to Portable Class Libraries. All functionality related to neural networks, machine learning etc. that are contained in the original frameworks have been ported to their PCL analogues.

The PCL libraries target the following platforms:

- Windows 8 and higher (formerly known as Metro or Windows Store apps)
- Windows Phone (Silverlight) 8 and higher
- .NET Framework 4.5 and higher

(When used in .NET, the libraries enable the ability to create WPF applications independent of *System.Drawing* and *System.Windows.Forms* assemblies, but that's another story :-)

The portable frameworks are available on Github:

- [Portable AForge.NET Framework](https://github.com/cureos/aforge)
- [Portable Accord.NET Framework](https://github.com/cureos/accord)

Comment: Thanks for eveything Gustafsson.